PowerShell is not launching explorer.exe using credentials stored in a .ps1 script - how can I correct the access is denied error that PsExec shows?
It has been a while since I've used PowerShell scripts, but we are trying to automate a process for an older software system in a market that is a few timezones removed from our normal IT crew's operating hours. Here is a snapshot of the script I'm working on:
$username = "DOMAIN\username"
$password = ConvetTo-SecureString "ThePassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

#Test credentials - remove # to disable comment mode
Write-Host "Username: $username"
Write-Host "Password: $password"
Write-Host "Credentials: $cred"

$sharePath = "\\192.168.X.X\folder\folder\folder"

Start-Process -FilePath "explorer.exe" -ArgumentList $sharePath -Credential $cred

The local admin for the market would usually manually launch the pathway listed in $sharePath and then enter the AD credentials to launch the software, and I know the creds I am using in the script are good, but PsExec reveals an access denied error when I attempt to run the script from there:
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied. At C:\users\username\desktop\script.ps1:12 char:1

Start-Process -FilePath "explorer.exe" -ArgumentList $sharePath -Credential $cred ...
CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
FullyQualifiedErrorID : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Is the code/syntax okay, but I'm missing some needed permissions for this local admin account to run this as an automated PowerShell process? Is it because of the script's current location? Or is my code flawed in some way?
Thanks for any help with this matter.
I've tried launching the $sharePath using Start-Process without any of the credential variables, and that works fine (I think this is because the credentials were entered manually earlier during this machine's startup today). It is when the -Credential tag comes into play that the script is throwing the "access is denied" error mentioned earlier.

Welcome to SO, Kris. Please [edit] the question and paste the PowerShell code and error message into the question as text. No screenshot pictures. Use the {} icon to format the text.

Use a file explorer and see if you have access to the $sharePath.  Put into the file explorer the address exactly as you have in the posted code.  Do you have x's in the path or just putting the x's so we do not know the exact path you are using?

Updated with requested edits - I do have access to the path using File Explorer. Manually entering the pathway and then creds when prompted does launch this directory location, so I figure it is something with the way I'm trying to pass the creds in the script that is the culprit here? Thanks all.

Yeah, just commenting out the full IP address for some obscurity.
